# Installing Debian Source Packages in Ubuntu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, software-installation

I need to install `Protobuf 3.6` which is available [here](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/protobuf) as a Debian source package on `Ubuntu Trusty/Xenial/Bionic`.

I'm looking to do this as a faster alternative over installing Protobuf from source.

Is such an installation possible/feasible? If yes, then what would be the best way to go about doing it?

Comment: It takes less than twenty minutes to build from source, you could have had the package a while ago... Or you could set up a PPA and have the PPA build systems take care of it for you.

Comment: Yea currently I'm building from source - I'm actually trying to speed up installation of a project I'm working on so as to have faster setup and build times. Currently building protobuf from source eats up a major chunk of the the time which results in slower tests.